# Spring Boot where is the compiled jar file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I have generated a gradle project from start.spring.io using spring initializr and added a few lines to it to print out the typical hello world message as well as the name given to the url. It works as expected when run from intellij idea on localhost:8080. But where is the jar file? I selected jar packaging and added the web dependency. I was under the impression that this would generate a single jar file including the web server which I could "just run". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command `gradle build`, the JAR is generated in `build/libs`.

Comment: Raphael Amoedo I tried but apparently, there is a time cap. I will accept it in 4 minutes.